# Can you control Explosions/ Smoke by frames?

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation

It looks like I have little influence on what the smoke/ explosion does. Sadly it goes directly from Frame 50 to 700.
What i want:

- Frame 50 to 250 smoke/ explosion reach the half of the final expansion
- Frame 250 to 450 smoke/ explosion should hold position but still smoking.
- Frame 450 to 550 smoke/ explosion reach now very fast the final expansion
- Frame 550 to 700 smoke/ explosion dissapear.

Is this somehow possible? Or do i have only influence on the speed with force fields?

I have a sphere which explode, should stop short, because its some futuristic stuff, and then finish the explosion

Answer (score 0):

You should do some complex stuff, buy you can achieve it.
In general you should work with "Time Scale" attribute of *Smoke Domain* > *Fluid* > *Settings* so you can "pause" the physics or slow it down.

If you are using the particles system to create the explosion, the same should be done in sync with the *Timestep* value under *Particle properties* > *Physics* > *Integration*

Here's how to pause the smoke:

[image]